# Simulate a single data point using parameter in a scatter chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, simulation, scatter-plot, powerbi-desktop

i have a requirement where i would like to simulate a new salary placement on a peer comparison scatter chart. Let say i have an employee moving from Sales department to HR department, by putting the new salary in the parameter i wish to see the new salary being included in the scatter chart and color as different color among the peers selected in HR department. Is this something doable using dax formula in Power bi? I am not allowed to put an image here. But the data would somehow look like this.

 
Table1 & Table2 - contains all employees current salary in the company with no relationship 
New Salary = Parameter.Value 

 
Steps: 
1. Select the Sales employee in table1 using slicer, and proposed a new salary in the parameter 
2. Select the peers from HR department in table2 
 *(so now i have one data point from table1 and some other data points from table2)*
 
3. Based on the selection on step 1 and 2, i want the data points all together to show up in the scatter chart with x-axis as the seniority in the company and y-axis as the salary. The new salary from the parameter will have to plot as red color to distinguish from the peers.

Thanks all in advanced for answer. I just need to know if this is doable in power bi using dax formula, and if yes, theoretically how to implement it.

Comment: Do you think two plots, one of top of the other, might do the trick? Maybe one plot for current salary, and another for the new salary?

Comment: But the scale on the x and y axis would be different, and it doesn't achieve the result i want.